# Print doesn't show anything in cosole but NSLog does

Tags: ios, swift

recently I created production scheme for my app, after that, the Xcode doesn't show anything whenever I use `print` and it just shows in console when I use `NSLog`. It happens both on development scheme and production scheme.
What is this issue come from?

for example

```
#if Production
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-PROD", ofType: "plist")  else { return }
        if let options = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        }
        print("[FIREBASE] Production mode.")
        NSLog("[FIREBASE] Production mode.")
#elseif Development
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-DEV", ofType: "plist")  else { return }
        if let options = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        }
        print("FIREBASE - Development mode.")
        NSLog("FIREBASE - Development mode.")
#endif
    
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { _, _ in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

here the first `NSLog` will print something in console, not `print()`. I don't know what I changed to make it like that, could anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly somewhere in your code you have overridden the `print()` function? Search your code for `public func print(`

Comment: No I didn't do something like that. Thanks for your post

Comment: Are you using any Pods or Packages? Right-click on `print()` and select `Jump to Definition` ... see if it takes you anywhere other than `Swift.Misc`